# Maven run test, then compile then other test

Tags: java, xml, maven, testng

My goal is to enable Maven to execute in one build:

1. Run a test in which a random username is written to a file in the resources
2. Then compile and run tests (using the compiled resource)

**What works**
With `test -Dtestgroups="purchase,checkorders"` running the other tests (2).

**What I miss**
Running the username creation, then compiling and testing.

My config:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
                <configfailurepolicy>continue</configfailurepolicy>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <url>${url}</url>
                    <browser>${browser}</browser>
                    <language>${language}</language>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <groups>${testGroups}</groups>
                <excludedGroups>${excludedGroups}</excludedGroups>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>${threadCount}</threadCount>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <workingDirectory>target/</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I've read some posts about executions but no success so far.

**UPDATE:**
I managed to make a plugin. See my answer below.

Comment: I think what you will need to do here is to write a mojo to handle your intiial test (1). When you add this plugin into the relevant pom you can set the execution parameters so that it runs earlier in the build lifecycle than the compilation phase, for example in the validation or generation phases. See this link for an explanation of the maven lifecycle: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_build_life_cycle.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make a plugin and also published it [on my github account](https://github.com/daafith/maven-repo). My Mojo's pom:

```
<groupId>credentials.plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>credentials-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
<name>Credentials Maven Plugin</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- dependencies to annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The Mojo.

```
@Mojo(name = "credentials")
public class CredentialsMojo extends AbstractMojo {

  @Parameter(property = "credentials.propertiesDirectory", defaultValue = "empty")
  private String propertiesDirectory;

  @Parameter(property = "credentials.propertiesFileName", defaultValue = "credentials")
  private String propertiesFileName;

  @Parameter(property = "credentials.nameLength", defaultValue = "6")
  private int nameLength;

  @Parameter(property = "credentials.password", defaultValue = "Welkom01@")
  private String password;

  public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
    getLog().info("Creating "+ propertiesFileName +".properties");
    parseDirectoryName();

    try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(propertiesDirectory + propertiesFileName +".properties"))) {
      tryCreateCredentialProperties(output);
    } catch (IOException io) {
      getLog().error(io);
    }
  }

  private void parseDirectoryName() {
    if (propertiesDirectory.equals("empty")) propertiesDirectory = "";
    addSlashToDirectory();
  }

  private void addSlashToDirectory() {
    if (propertiesDirectory.equals("") || propertiesDirectory.endsWith("/")) return;
    propertiesDirectory = propertiesDirectory + File.separator;
  }

  private OutputStream tryCreateCredentialProperties(OutputStream output) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    final String username = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(nameLength);
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty("username", username);
    prop.setProperty("password", password);
    prop.store(output, null);
    getLog().info("Username = " + username);
    getLog().info("Password = " + password);
    return output;
  }
}
```

And in the project using the plugin:

```
<properties>
  <nameLength>16</nameLength>
  <password>qwerty@01</password>
  <propertiesDirectory>src/test/resources</propertiesDirectory>
  <propertiesFileName>foobar</propertiesFileName>
</properties>
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>credentials.plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>credentials-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <configuration>
    <nameLength>${nameLength}</nameLength>
    <password>${password}</password>
    <propertiesDirectory>${propertiesDirectory}</propertiesDirectory>
    <propertiesFileName>${propertiesFileName}</propertiesFileName>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```